# Question title still appearing on browser page title after discard

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Whenever you discard a question you were about to ask, all fields come clear but the page title in the browser opened tab stays the same.

- Ask a question and you are provided with a page entitled `Ask a Question` :

[image]

- Start typing your question and the page title refreshes to show the title:

[image]

- Click on the *discard* link next to the `Post Your Question` button:

[image]

- All fields come clear except the page title in the browser tab which doesn't go back to `Ask a Question`:

[image]

Is this a bug or is this intended?